# Month and Year Part from GetDate

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am using a gridview in my asp.net application in which i want to limit the dataset to requests that are submitted in the current month and year

Iam new to application development and thinking in the below way

to get the month and year part from the getdate() function and then compare it with the month and year of the receiveddate column in our table in the where condition

My select statement would be like below

select requestno,receiveddate,businessneed from customerrequests
where receiveddate = getdate()

in the above sql statement how do i acheive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like below:

```
DECLARE @FirstDate DATETIME    
SELECT @FirstDate = DATEADD(month, DateDiff(Month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)

SELECT 
      requestno,receiveddate,businessneed 
FROM 
      customerrequests 
WHERE 
      receiveddate >= @FirstDate
```

Hope this Helps!!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you could do this:

- In SQL by passing two parameters for month and year.  This is what your questions sounds like and can be done by just doing this:

  `select requestno,receiveddate,businessneed from customerrequests where YEAR(receiveddate) = YEAR(getdate()) AND MONTH(receiveddate) = MONTH(getdate())`
- The other way would be to construct a date object on the client side and pass that in to your query and then just use regular date comparison techniques.

Hope that helps.